# Can't get team using Graph API and Teams free

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Are there any known issues with using the Graph API to talk to Teams, when it's the [free offer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sign-up-for-teams-free-70aaf044-b872-4c32-ac47-362ab29ebbb1)?

I can authenticate to the Graph endpoint and retrieve my user details, setting the AAD tenant to my "default directory". If I look at my group memberships with `GET /me/memberOf`, I can see that there are Microsoft 365 groups for each of my teams. But as soon as I try to do anything Teams-related, like `GET /teams/{group_id}` I get a 403 error: "Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest."

Comment: What type of accounts are you using? Work/School or Personal? I think that the teams free comes with limited support for Graph API Support. You can also provide the full error from Graph.

Comment: @Danstan It's a personal account, and as stated in the question, it's the free version. I can access the regular paid version at work, without any problems

Comment: In this case, I see that on the docs [Get to Retrieve the properties and relationships of the specified Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) does not support delegated permission on personal accounts and that can be why you get 403

Comment: @Danstan Huh, so it does. Actually, does authenticating to your default directory count as using a personal account? In the portal it looks like a regular AAD tenant, with my account showing up as a guest